# How to crop substring on a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

In powershell I am trying to read a file named `source.txt` which has a content similar to this:

```
\\14.261.214.1\TEST Path OK\DIQ\V199.32\DOWN\15.7.0.8574
```

And I'm trying to crop only the suffix version (which is `15.7.0.8574`) and to append it a file named `destination.txt`.

like this:

```
Version = 15.7.0.8574
```

I was able to read the file content using `Get-Content c:\scripts\source.txt` how to I crop and save to destination file

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
get-content source.txt |Split-Path -Leaf | set-content result.txt
```

Update for V2 you will have to use a variation :

```
Split-Path -Leaf -Path (gc .\source.txt)
```

Comment: This is not working, it is saving the file name in results.txt rather than the version

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
$regex = ‘\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,5}\b$’
$value = select-string -Path "c:\scripts\source.txt" -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } 
write-host $value
```